# concatenar texto de un TextBox a una celda o linea de un DataGridView - C#

Tags: c#, vb

tengo el siguiente formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero que al momento de escribir algo en el TextBox Comentario y darle al Botón Agregar, este me concatene lo que puse en el Textbox a la fila que este seleccionada del DataGridView y lo coloque al final

por ejemplo

escribí "NORMAL" y le di al Botón Agregar, este es el resultado que espero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer eso?

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado

Comment: Hola, lo logre solucionar de esta forma

```private void buttonAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value += textBox1.Text;
}```